# Why does wsimport suddenly generate client code that uses wrapped parameters?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, wsimport

I learned web services a few years ago with Axis2, and so I've been using it since then.

I've always hated the fact that Axis2 generates client stubs using wrapped parameters instead of the original types.  I understand that when you're using complex objects as parameters there's really no choice as those objects need to get serialized, but when your method requires a String and maybe returns a String, wrapping those in some xxx.yyy.Get and xxx.yyy.GetResponse parameters seems like overkill to me.  Since I'm using JSON as input and output on all my services now, I'm working with Strings only.

Later in my learnings I discovered I could still create my services with Eclipse's Axis2 plugin, but instead of using the Axis2 stubs, I could use the Java JDK's wsimport tool instead to create clients without all the clutter of the wrapped types.

So, for a service method "String getData(String param)", I could have a client call that looks like "servicePort.getData(stringParam)", where "stringParam" is obviously a String.

That is, until today :-(

For some reason, today I created a new service, deployed it on my server, and called wsimport on it, only to find out that the generated client was using wrapped types.

For example, here's my service definition, from which I create a WSDL and then the service code using Eclipse's Axis2 plugin:

```
public String get(String param){
   return null;
}
```

And, here's the wsimport-generated client:

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "getResponse", targetNamespace = "http://...", partName = "parameters")
public GetResponse get(
    @WebParam(name = "get", targetNamespace = "http://...", partName = parameters)
    Get parameters);
```

On a web service I had coded beforehand, I ended up with the following client code :

```
@WebMethod(action = "urn:get")
@WebResult(targetNamespace = "http://...")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "get", targetNamespace = "http://...", className = "xxx.yyy.Get")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "getResponse", targetNamespace = "http://...", className = "xxx.yyy.GetResponse")
public String get(
    @WebParam(name = "param", targetNamespace = "http://...")
    String param);
```

Here's the wsimport command I'm using to generate the client (on Windows, from my JDK's bin directory) :

```
.\wsimport -p <package name> -s <target src directory> -extension -verbose -Xnocompile <webserviceUrl?wsdl>
```

And the wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xsd="http://..." xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://...">
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://...">
        <xs:element name="get">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="param" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="getResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="xsd:get"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="xsd:getResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ServicePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="get">
        <wsdl:input message="xsd:getRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:get"/>
        <wsdl:output message="xsd:getResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:getResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ServiceSoap11Binding" type="xsd:ServicePortType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="get">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:get" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="ServiceSoap12Binding" type="xsd:ServicePortType">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="get">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:get" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="ServiceHttpBinding" type="xsd:ServicePortType">
    <http:binding verb="POST"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="get">
        <http:operation location="get"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Service">
    <wsdl:port name="ServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="xsd:ServiceSoap11Binding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/Service"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="ServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="xsd:ServiceSoap12Binding">
        <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/Service"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="ServiceHttpEndpoint" binding="xsd:ServiceHttpBinding">
        <http:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/Service"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I have found other questions and answers here on StackOverflow and other forums for the "enableWrapperStyle" thing in a custom binding file, tried it, didn't work.  Anyhow, this flag seems to allow either generating method signatures with wrapped types (which I don't want), or signatures returning void and using some Holder types in the signature for return values (which I don't want either).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you find any solutions by now ?

Comment: In order to expose a intuitive client of my api to my customers, I need change the : partName = "parameters". Is it posible?         I will try with : "A customization file" > http://java-soa.blogspot.pe/2008/07/parameter-customization-in-jax-ws.html